# How to write Like query in Linq to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

i tried the following code...

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        using (DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
        {
            List<Student> studentsList = db.Students.Where(m=>m.name.Contains("d")==query).ToList();
            return View(studentsList);                
        }
    }
```

but if i use "Contains" then it gives me error..
please help

Comment: which error? This should appear in your question.

Comment: `Contains` returns `bool` and you are comparing it to a `String` (query). I believe you were looking to do `db.Students.Where(m=>m.name.Contains("d") && m.name == query).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the "d" is for but you should just do

```
List<Sudent> studentList = db.Students.Where(m=>m.name.Contains(query)).ToList();
```

Or if you want the name to contain query and "d" then

```
List<Sudent> studentList = db.Students
    .Where(m=>m.name.Contains("d") && m.name.Contains(query)).ToList();
```

I hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

In this case using "Contains" is not necessary :

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
    using (DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
    {
        List<Student> studentsList = db.Students.Where(m=>m.name==query).ToList();
        return View(studentsList);                
    }
}
```

Or if you want using multiple conditions ,you should use "&&" Operator between conditions , you can use this code :

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
    using (DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
    {
        List<Student> studentsList = db.Students
       .Where(m=>m.name.Contains("d") && m.name==query).ToList();
        return View(studentsList);                
    }
}
```